# Show that $f$ is a linear map if $f$ is differentiable and its derivative is constant:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Show that if $f:ℝ^m→ℝ^n$ is a differentiable function whose derivative function $f′$ is a constant function and such that $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is a is a linear map.

I am a little lost on this. I know that the result for $m=n=1$ is $f(x)=cx$, but I am not sure how to prove this. I am assuming I need to use the idea of the derivative as a linear map. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof in the multidimensional case is analogous to the case $n=m=1$.  The key tool is that if a function has derivative $0$, it is constant.  Thus any two functions with the same derivative are equal up to a constant.

Fix some constant matrix which gives the derivative at each point.  Can you find an explicit antiderivative for this matrix? (recall that the entries of the derivative matrix of a function are the partial derivatives)  Then you know that your function differs from this function by a constant.  Now use $f(0)=0$ to find the constant.

If you are having a hard time seeing this, try working out the case $n=m=2$.